# What is the limit of $\frac{y^4}{x^2+y^4}$, when $(x,y) \to (0,0)$?

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus

What is the limit of $\frac{y^4}{x^2+y^4}$, when $(x,y) \to (0,0)$? The first test is taking $y = kx$, then pushing $x \to 0$, the result is $0$. My best guess is that the limit should be zero, how to actually prove it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hint: Take $x=y^2$ and you will get.

Answer (score 1):

If $x=0$, then $\frac{y^4}{x^2+y^4}=1$. So, the limit cannot be $0$, and therefore there is no limit.